# How to increase speed of SQL query from 2 CONNECT BY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 3 tables: t1, t2, t3.

t1 - hierarchical table (have id and parent_id)

t1 is connected with t2, t2 is connected with t3 (join)

Input: some id's of t1

It is necessary to construct a tree up on these identifiers (to collect all parental nodes)

Then to construct a tree down, having stuck together t2 and t3

It is also necessary to restore value of a t3name (from t3) of their children for parental tops

Output: it is necessary to receive hierarchical trees for each t3name

My SQL-request, but it is very slow:

Miniexample:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b607/2

```
SELECT id, name, t3name FROM 
(SELECT distinct t1.id as id, 
                 t1.parent as parent, 
           t1.name as name, 
           connect_by_root(t3.name) as t3name
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.t2_id = t2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
        ON t2.t3_id = t3.id
    START WITH t1.id in (83, 98, 9, 19, 4, 101)
        CONNECT BY PRIOR t1.parent = t1.id)
WHERE t3name IS NOT NULL
START WITH parent = 0
    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent and PRIOR t3name = t3name
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b607/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to help you tune your query without seeing the execution plan, but if I understand you right then you need the 2 joins only for the value of `t3name`.

if that's really the case then try to first get the hierarchical data from table1 and join the results to table2 and table3.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT id, name, t3name FROM 
(SELECT distinct t1.id as id, 
                 t1.parent as parent, 
           t1.name as name, 
           t3.name as t3name
    FROM (select tt1.name, tt1.id, tt1.parent, connect_by_root(tt1.t2_id) t2_id
         from table1 tt1 
         START WITH tt1.id in (83, 98, 9, 19, 4, 101)
        CONNECT BY PRIOR tt1.parent = tt1.id) t1
    JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.t2_id = t2.id
    JOIN table3 t3
        ON t2.t3_id = t3.id
    )
WHERE t3name IS NOT NULL
START WITH parent = 0
    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent and PRIOR t3name = t3name;
```

I added to your fiddle some primary keys (to see if I can make it use the indexes) and put both queries. See [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75bb0/1)